# EF Core Configuration IsRequired based on Condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Lets say I have the following EF Core Entity:

```
public class Day : AuditEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsGame { get; set; }

    public GameDay? GameDay { get; set; }

    public StoryDay? StoryDay { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to make a configuration so that if IsGame is true then GameDay is required otherwise StoryDay is required? I had thought you could maybe solve it in the following manner:

```
public class DayConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Day>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Day> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(d => d.GameDay).IsRequired(d => d.IsGame)
    }
}
```

But obviously IsRequired does not take a function as a parameter.

Comment: This is possible in EF Core 3 and later with `HasCheckConstraint` at the entity level. That translates to a CHECK constraint at the table level

Comment: Possibly `builder.HasCheckConstraint("CHK_SomeName","GameDayId is NOT NULL OR ScoreDayID is not null");`